# Story behind Lord Mahavishnu lying on a 5 headed serpent in the ocean

Tags: vishnu

What is the story behind Lord Mahavishnu lying on a serpent with 5 heads in an ocean?

Comment: What are you looking for, the reason he sleeps on a serpent or the reason why he sleeps in an ocean of milk, or both?

Comment: Actually i mean both...

Comment: http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/9404/how-did-the-serpent-adisesha-become-bed-for-lord-vishnu?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: @Sarvabhouma - This question is first time asked on this website.