# Why Lord Vishnu is mostly seen in resting or sleeping position?

Tags: vishnu

Why Lord Vishnu is mostly seen in Resting or Sleeping position?

Other god are not seen in resting or sleeping position like Lord Shiva, Brahmdev, Ganesh or any other God.

But in many images Lord Vishnu is in resting position or sleeping position and Goddess Mahalakshmi is doing Paadseva.

Comment: similar https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/9404/how-did-the-serpent-adisesha-become-bed-for-lord-vishnu?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: @Friendy it is not similar question. I'm asking y only  Lord Vishnu is in resting or sleeping position.

Answer (score 5):

> SHANTAKARAM BHUJANGASHAYANAM PADMANABHAM SURESHAM, 
>   VISHWADHARAM GAGAN SADRISHAM MEGHAVARNAM SHUBHANGAM | 
>   LAKSHMIKANTAN KAMALNAYANAM YOGIMIRDHYANA GAMYAM, 
>   VANDE VISHNUM BHAVA BHAYAHARAM SARVA LOKAIKNATHAM ||
>
> > I worship that Lord Vishnu who has a peaceful body
> >     (postures); who rests on Sheshanaga (the mighty serpant - cobra); who
> >     has a lotus in his navel, who is the base of the world, who is like
> >     the sky; who has a colour like cloud, who is the lord of Lakshmi
> >     (wealth); who has eyes like lotus; who is seen by yogis in their
> >     meditation; who is the remover of all the differences and who is the
> >     only Lord of all the three Lokas (Worlds), I worship such Lord Vishnu.

Vishnu rests on Sheshnag because it symbolizes that one who has reached the Ultimate Enlightenment, should be in peace and without tension or stress of mind, knowing that Sheshnag, a snake (allegorical to materialistic troubles) is hovering above him.

So one who wants peace, must worship Vishnu.

Why does Lord Vishnu rest on Sheshnag?

> Brahma Purana:
>   The second virtue (resting on the Sheshanaga) must be considered as
>   the sub-virtue of the peaceful appearance. Scriptures describe
>   Sheshanaga as Kala also. Sheshanaga is a highly
>   poisonous snake. But Lord Vishnu rests on him without fear or
>   worries. One should not to lose patience even while facing the kala
>   itself; instead strive to ride on it, only then can one
>   remain in peaceful appearance. If the fear overpowers, it may
>   shatter peace. The worshipers who want salvation should be peaceful.

Why does Vishnu rest on a Sagar (Ksheerodak, Garbhodak or Karanodak). Chanakyaneeti explains it thus.

> KA CHINTA MAM JIVANE YADI HARIIVISHVAMMBHARO GEEYATE, 
>   NO CHEDARBHAKA JIVANAY JANANISTANYAM KATHM NIRMYET |
>   ITYALOCHYMUHURMUHURYADUPATE LAKSHMIPATE KEWAL 
>   TVATPADAMSHUJASEVANEN SATATAM KALOMAYA NEEYATE ||
>
> > If God Hari Vishnu is known as VISHVAMBHAR (feeder of the
> >     world) I need not worry for anything in the world. If he were not
> >     there, where the milk would come from in the breast of a mother before
> >     child's birth. So God filled the breast of a new mother with complete
> >     food that is milk.

Comment: Lakshmi doing Padaseva means that one who's mastered the Self, has no need for money. In fact money and pleasures follow Him like winds in a storm.

Comment: Regarding the snake part, you might be interested to notice that Shiva has a snake coiled up around His neck as well. It could strangle Him anytime or bite Him. But Shiva, like Vishnu, is relaxed and aloof. Always in the eternal yogi position. He symbolizes the tremendous power of Yoga, and that which leads to fearlessness and knowledge.

Comment: Why don't you add the comments in your answer by editing it?