# Does Krishna claim identity with Vishnu as supreme being in Bhagavad Gita?

Tags: vishnu, krishna

He of course claims that HE is supreme.  The question is does he recognize other supreme beings and claim he is one with them and they are one with him.  When he says "Among Adityas I am Vishnu" “Aditya” refers to 12 sons born to Aditi and her husband Kashyapa.  This Vishnu is not the supreme being of Vishnu Purana, Bhagavatam and so forth.  Interestingly, the word "Narayana" does not occur in Gita.

(1) This specific question is not answered in response to the other question.  The "Vishnu among Adityas" is not an answer.

(2) Arjuna addresses him as"Vishnu" but that is not the same as Krishna claiming to be Vishnu.

Comment: Good Qn. You may refer [this answer](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/21205/1049), from the linked post.

Comment: It is not even remotely the same.  I have already explained the "among the adityas" is just a figure of speech - like "among the rivers, i am Ganga".  That doesn't mean he claims identity with Ganga.

Comment: When he says "I am Ganga", he means that he is Ganga among rivers and claims identity with them. Not a figure of speech.

Comment: Wording the question in clear manner  will help the users clearly understand what you are exactly looking for. So it's better if you repeat your main concern in body section ,explaining the question clearly. This will reduce the chances of confusion and also Will reduce the chances of marking it as   duplicate if it is clearly not. .

Comment: In title u asked "Does Krishna claim **identity with Vishnu**" and in body u asked " The question is does he recognize **other supreme beings** and claim he is one with **them and they** are one with him", other supreme beings means more than one supreme. Title and body are not matching. So, are u asking about Vishnu only or others as well?

Answer (score 1):

In Gita, Krishna has established his identity with all the 3 famous deities: BrahmA -- Vishnu -- Shiva[linga]. This implies that all the ultimate gods are in oneness of supreme One. My answer is based on how Vishnu is depicted in popular culture.

Excerpts from [this post](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/21205/1049);

## Vishnu

There is a namesake Vishnu reference, which refers to the sons of Aditi:

> BG 10.21 - Among the Adityas [viz *Dhata, Mitra, Aryama, Rudra, Varuna, Surya, Bhaga, Vivasvan, Pusa, Savita, Tvasta and Visnu*.-Tr.] **I am *Vishnu***; ...  -- translation Gambhirananda

Few verses in chapter-11 depicts the famous all deity form:

> BG 11.10 - Having **many faces and eyes, possessing many wonderful sights**, adorned with numerous celestial ornaments, holding many uplifted heavenly weapons;
> BG 11.15 - Arjuna said O God, I see in Your body **all the gods** as also hosts of (various) classes of beings; Brahma the ruler, sitting on a lotus seat, and all the heavenly sages and **serpents**.
> BG 11.16 - I see You as possessed of **numerous arms, bellies, mouths and eyes; as having infinite forms all around**. O Lord of the Universe, O Cosmic Person, I see not Your limit nor the middle, nor again the beginning!
> BG 11.17 - I see You as wearing a diadem, **wielding a mace**, and **holding a disc**; a mass of brilliance glowing all around, difficult to look at from all sides, possessed of the radiance of the blazing fire and sun, and immeasurable.
> BG 11.22 Those who are the Rudras, the Adityas, the Vasus and the Sadhyas, the Visve (-devas), the two Asvins, the Maruts and the Usmapas, and hosts of Gandharvas, Yaksas, demons and Siddhas-all of those very ones gaze at You, being indeed struck with wonder.
> BG 11.23 - O mighty-armed One, seeing Your **immense form with many mouths and eyes, having numerous arms, thighs and feet, with many bellies**, and fearful with many teeth, the creatures are struck with terror, and so am I.

[image]

Another famous depiction of Vishnu is sleeping on [Adi Shesha is discussed here](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/19702/1049).

[image]

Another form depicts as of whole universe silently pervades as the Vishnu:

> BG 9.4 - This **whole universe is pervaded by Me** in My unmanifested form. All beings exist in Me, but I am not contained in them!

[image]

Comment: `I am the only enjoyer and master of all sacriﬁces. Therefore, those who do not recognize My true transcendental nature fall down.` Bg 9.24 And lord Vishnu is known as Yajna Purusha in many scriptures including Bg 3.9.

Comment: You first say -"good question" then you yourself answered the question then marked it duplicate. Weird.

Comment: @Rohit., you got the order wrong. I first marked as duplicate, but then felt that people may not agree with it due to nature of both posts. You can already see another linked duplicate with higher votes 3 or 4. Hence, I wrote the answer as an excerpt from it. By the time, I wrote the answer, the auto-comment of duplicate was already >5 mins. So I wrote it in a separate comment, suggesting that which answer the OP has to refer, as the accepted answer of Tezz doesn't discuss from Gita perspective. Hope this clears the doubts!